# Construct two examples of covering spaces arc-connected with 6 branches (leaves) over the torus T that are not isomorphic.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Construct two examples of covering spaces arc-connected with 6 braches/leaves over the torus T that are not isomorphic.

I would like to know what does it mean "6 leaves", and any hint to solve this exercise would be appreciated.

If $T= S^1 \times S^1$ I know that $\mathbb{R}^2$  is the universal covering space of $T=\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$

Comment: Maybe they mean that it has to be a degree 6 covering?

Comment: Do you know about the correspondence between isomorphism classes of coverings and conjugacy classes of subgroups of $\pi_1$?

Comment: No, can you let me know, please. @William

Comment: You seem to already know about universal coverings, maybe you also know that if $U\to B$ is a universal covering (with $B$ connected) then $\pi_1(B)$ acts freely on $U$ in a fibre-preserving way, and that the action is transitive on each fibre. Given a subgroup $H\subset \pi_1(B)$ you can form a covering space $U/H \to B$, and the cardinality of the fibres are $|\pi_1(B)/H|$. The interesting result is that $H$ and $H'$ are conjugate in $\pi_1(B)$ iff $U/H$ and $U/H'$ are isomorphic over $B$. You can find the result in Hatcher or in Harper and Greenberg (and also many others).

Comment: The classification theorem is sort of the "sledgehammer solution." If this is an exercise for a course and you haven't seen the classification theorem yet, you will need a more elementary way of solving this problem. Try directly constructing covers of degree $6$ using the universal covering.